# ANY in MySQL subrequest

Tags: mysql, request, mysql-error-1064, any

I have a couple of tables in MySQL and I made a request to them. In this request I make a subrequest, as I have field f1 in table t1 which is sometimes NULL, sometimes NOT NULL, and in case it is NOT NULL I want to select the field f2 from table t1, and ignore it when f1 is NULL.
The field f1 is present in both tables, it is unique in t2 and may be not unique in t1.

I made the following subrequest:

```
//[main request here]
IF (t1.f1 IS NOT NULL, (SELECT t2.f1 AND t2.f2 FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.f1 = t2.f1),'')
//[main request continues here]
```

MySQL sais: `Invalid query: Subquery returns more than 1 row`

I understood that I have to include somehow ANY in the subrequest, I tried different ways but I still got the same error or a misspell. 
Can please anybody help me?

Comment: SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * , [different fields here not mentioned in the subrequest]
IF (t1.f1 IS NOT NULL, (SELECT t2.f1 AND t2.f2 FROM t1, t2 WHERE t1.f1 = t2.f1),''), 
[more fields not mentioned in the subrequest here] 
FROM t1, [other tables not mentioned in the subrequest here] 
WHERE [...] 
ORDER BY [...] 
It works well without the subrequest howeber.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your subselect is joining t1 and t2, so it's not returning a unique row, because t1 has multiple matching rows. Try:

```
IF (t1.f1 IS NOT NULL, (SELECT t2.f1 AND t2.f2 FROM t2 WHERE t1.f1 = t2.f1),'')
```

Comment: You didn't ask for t2.t2, you wrote `t2.f1 AND t2.f2`. If you just want t2.f2, change that.

Comment: I need t2.f2, otherwise the subrequest it is useless, I already have f1 in t1. :)

Comment: Change `SELECT t2.f1 AND t2.f2` to `SELECT t2.f2` like I said.

Comment: What is it printing instead of t2.f2?

Comment: Found it in the MySQL documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/correlated-subqueries.html